# Generic word for any kind of unit inside the company

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I'm translating a document template, to be filled out later for specific purposes. It has a table in the beginning which indicates who exactly produced a particular document. In the first line of the table, we have

> **Подразделение**: *наименование*
>
> [image]

"Подразделение" is literally "subdivision", which means "a company's unit of any size and type". Thus, the first line says "Subdivision: Name".

The company has units called "such-and-such department", "such-and-such division", ".. unit", ".. site", ".. laboratory" - and I need a catch-all term for this table.

Will **Business unit** suit the purpose? Can we call, say, a laboratory is "a business unit"?

I felt strange using it because a laboratory does not do any "business".

Comment: Yes, *business unit* is the typical term in corporate America (speaking as a corporate American drone: #44173).

Comment: Division, department, unit, group, section, branch, and several more.

Comment: @HotLicks - I need a word that would cover all of these, because "Production Department" (for example) would be written by the employee who will fill out the form I'm translating. So I'll use "Business Unit:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, business unit would be suitable. The [definition according to www.businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/business-unit.html) is

> A logical element or segment of a company (such as accounting, production, marketing) representing a specific business function, and a definite place on the organizational chart, under the domain of a manager. Also called department, division, or a functional area.

The research lab at Kodak was referred to as a business unit when I worked there, so I don't think there is a problem using it for a laboratory that is part of a company. You could use "department" if you think "business unit" might be confusing.